# Java Spring Using EntityManger or not?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, entity

So I was looking at using Spring with JPA/Hibernate for a MySQL db access and saw two different methods. One has has a config file application.properties

```
# DataSource settings: set here your own configurations for the database 
# connection. In this example we have "netgloo_blog" as database name and 
# "root" as username and password.
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/netgloo_blog
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root

# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy =       org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager)

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

and no config bean. It just goes into defining the entity and the controller (source is http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/10/27/using-mysql-in-spring-boot-via-spring-data-jpa-and-hibernate/)

but then you got basically the same application, that has the same application.properties (shorter) file but also has a configuration bean that defines an entitymanagerfactor and uses entitymanger.persist instead of the previous one's use of a repository.save() method. (http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/10/06/spring-boot-data-access-with-jpa-hibernate-and-mysql/)

I'm not asking the differences between repository and entitymanger, I'm wondering why one has the separate Java config file alongside the application.properties and has to go through all the entitymanagerfactor code. Its a lot less code not having the entity manager, so why would you use it?

Both programs do the same thing, you visit localhost/create?user=name to create a user in the table, same retrieval methods.

Is entitymanager outdated or something?

Thanks

Comment: Both use `EntityManager.persist` in the end. Also Spring Boot already provides an `EntityManagerFactory` to inject `EntityManager` instances. So you don't need to configure anything additional. You can use either one with the same amount of configuration. The only difference is one uses the plain JPA API the other uses the convenient Spring Data JPA abstraction.

Comment: Okay thanks. I was wondering why spring data JPA seems so easy to use over the JPA API.